# ¿Porque no puedo hacer push en git si ya clone el repositorio?

Tags: git-push

Estoy trabajando con gitlab clone mi repositorio y podia hacer push, realice unos cambios, volvi a hacer push pero ya no me dejo, no se cual sea el motivo de esto, me marca el siguiente error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ahi mismo te lo dice, tienes cambios en tu en tu repo de gitlab que no tienes de manera local, puedes hacer `pull` y despues tu `push` o puedes forzar el push con `git push -f`

Comment: Como te dice @Gerardo ya probaste haciendo un pull antes de tu push ??

Comment: si era eso, muchas gracias